# V8 unsigned int operations

Tags: javascript, v8, jit, typed-arrays

When perform bitwise operation (bit shift specificly) on js numbers they are casted to `int32`, so in theory they must fit in v8's `smi` (it must be fast befor jit, and most likely after), but what happens when same operations performed on `uint32` ?

for example

```
const arr = new Uint32Array([0x1]);
arr[0] = ((arr[0] << 31) >>> 0);
```

- does v8 perform unnecessary unsigned right shift?
- does v8 perform type casts like uint32 => double => int32 => double => uint32 => double => uint32, or something similar, instaed of performing all operations on uint32?
- what if use standart array instad of typed one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(V8 developer here.)

> they are casted to `int32`, so in theory they must fit in v8's `smi`

No, Smi range is a signed 31-bit integer (on 32-bit platforms as well as pointer-compressed 64-bit platforms). That doesn't prevent the optimizing compiler from using untagged 32-bit integer values for local values (such as intermediate results, or the values loaded from typed arrays).

> does v8 perform unnecessary unsigned right shift?

No, at least not in optimized code.

> does v8 perform type casts like uint32 => double => int32 => double => uint32 => double => uint32, or something similar, instaed of performing all operations on uint32?

No, at least not in optimized code.

> what if use standart array instad of typed one?

Depends on type feedback, i.e. on what kinds of objects/values are in the array, and/or have been in arrays that have been processed at the same source code positions that this array has gone through. Standard arrays never store `uint32` values; they'll either store generic tagged values (i.e. the result, having its top bit set, must be boxed as a `HeapNumber`), or double values, so you'll get `double` -> `int32` -> `double` conversions.

In summary, the given snippet will be more efficient when you use `Uint32Array`s. However, keep in mind that typed arrays have more per-object overhead than regular arrays, so which array type is the overall better choice depends on the rest of your app and can't be decided based on a two-line snippet.